# Losing reputation?

Tags: discussion

I have a post and it was doing fine with an answer and a few upvotes but someone came and edited the entire post changing the title and some significant key words throughout the question. I erased his edits and I think I lost 5 reputation points by doing it but why?

Comment: I think you might have confused why you lost 5 rep points. Your reputation tab shows you gained 35 (upvotes) and lost 40 due to a serial upvote correction. I don't believe the edits affected anything.

Comment: What is a serial upvote correction?

Comment: To find out, follow the link next to that entry in your rep history...

Comment: @codeMonkey http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I erased his edits and lost 5 reputation but why?

You are conflating two separate things - your rollback and the loss of 5 reputation. Those are different things.

A loss of 5 rep would happen when someone who previously upvoted your question retracts the upvote (aka an un-upvote).

There really isn't a way to tell why someone did that.

---

Another way it could happen is if your posts were serially upvoted by someone and the system [reversed these votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).